# Allow user to download image from embedded chart in Safari

Tags: visualforce, analytics

I am using `<analytics:reportChart>` in a VF page. The users want to be able to download the image of the chart. I am able to do this fine in Chrome but they tell me it doesn't work in Safari.  I can't find an attribute to allow this. Or do I need to do something with JS?

Comment: What happens on right-click in Safari(

Comment: Nothing, no option to download. That's the problem. Super odd